# codeigniter poedit translations not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, gettext

I am stucked with this for better part of the day.
I have 7 languages. All .mo files are complied and their content is ok. This is my code for setting translation:

```
$lang_path = FCPATH.APPPATH.'language/locales';
putenv('LANG='.$language.'.UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language.'.UTF-8');
bindtextdomain('lang', $lang_path);
textdomain('lang');


//example
echo _('PRIVACY'); //->this shuold return translation from .mo which is "privatnost"
```

Funny thing is that if I change en_US language, by adding translation noting happens.
I just get key from _(key) getetxt. I checked my Mac locales and en_US and ru_RU are there.

Any idea how to debug this?

UPDATE

**I figure out.
What a stupid problem. For some reason chmod was off for all directories.
I changed it to 755. And viola everything is working.**

Comment: I had a similar problem. I changed chmod to 755. If you are runnign AFS file system .mo files want be able to be read.